# HTTPD server not starting after disabling these modules mod_include, mod_info, mod_autoindex and mod_userdir

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, rhel

As per this article "4. Disable Unnecessary Modules"

Ref: http://www.tecmint.com/apache-security-tips/

It’s always good to minor the chances of being a victim of any web attack. So it’s recommended to disable all those modules that are not in use currently. I disabled these modules **mod_imap, mod_include, mod_info, mod_userdir, mod_autoindex**.

After that httpd server is no restarting. Can you please help me to findout the issue.

I didn't get any errors on error_log or access_log

I got this following response if try to restart

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-02-01 10:02:08 CET; 1min 15s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 58603 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 58601 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 58601 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

> apachectl configtest

"AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf:
Invalid command 'IndexOptions', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

```
#
# Directives controlling the display of server-generated directory listings.
#
# Required modules: mod_authz_core, mod_authz_host,
#                   mod_autoindex, mod_alias
#
# To see the listing of a directory, the Options directive for the
# directory must include "Indexes", and the directory must not contain
# a file matching those listed in the DirectoryIndex directive.
#

#
# IndexOptions: Controls the appearance of server-generated directory
# listings.
#
IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort

# We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If
# you do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.
#
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/httpd/icons/"

<Directory "/usr/share/httpd/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The error I got in this line I don't know what went wrong `IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort`

Comment: have you tried "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" to get error details?

Comment: `No journal files were found.` i got for "journalctl -xe"

Comment: Start by not disabling a whole bunch of modules in one go, but disable them one by one, and see if Apache still starts after each one. Plus, do a config test (`apachectl -t`) and see what that has to say.

Comment: Check if you have to remove configuration directives for the removed modules. To investigate further, reenable the modules one at a time to find out, whoch one is causing the trouble. To possibly get error messages directly printed to the console, don't start the service, but apache directly (`apachectl start` or somesuch).

Comment: I got syntax error on line 16 of autoindex file. I Updated the issue

Comment: didn't you disabled mod_autoindex? i believe you need to remove configurations of that module as Tom mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are answering your own question really:

Note what you said:
" I disabled these modules mod_imap, mod_include, mod_info, mod_userdir, mod_autoindex."

And note the error you now have:
"AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf: Invalid command 'IndexOptions', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration".

**You just have to remove the Option "IndexOptions", since it depends on mod_autoindex, which you have unloaded**

When Apache complains about not knowing a directive or an option it means that either you misspelled it, or that the module that provides it is not being loaded.

Comment: issue is not because of this the sslcertificatechain file is not accessible in ssl module. privilege issue. Also I identified userdir.conf , autoindex.conf is not removed from the system. yesterday it's solved anyway thanks for the information this will be helpful for others.